# Form of Lorentz Transformation in 3D space

Tags: transformation, orthogonality, special-relativity

[image]

My idea so far: I know that it must satisfy the relation:
$$ L^T g L=g $$ where $g=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$
hence I deduced from this it must preserve the quantity $$c^2t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$$

I am unsure as to the next step I should take?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that every proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation is a composition of a pure boost and a rotation among the three spatial dimensions?

Comment: No  I have not met that yet in the course... is there any way to do it without that knowledge?